# Json Jackson Mapper Generic Map Type issue

Tags: java, json, jackson

This is my firs titme dealing with Type Maps and everytime i try to map the node to my Actual Type Object which has a custom property key as FooType with a `Set<Integer>` values. Here is how my Object looks like

```
public class Foo {
    private String some;
    Map<FooTypes,Set<Integer>> foos;

    public Map<FooTypes, Set<Integer>> getFoos() {
        return foos;
    }
    public void setFoos(Map<FooTypes, Set<Integer>> map) {
        this.foos = map;
    }
    public String getSome() {
        return some;
    }
    public void setSome(String some) {
        this.some = some;
    }
}

public class FooTypes {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Now everytime i try to use the mapper to read the value :-

`List <Foo> response = mapper.readValue("/home/foo/foo.json",List.class);`

I get an error stating that :-

`Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class cruft.FooTypes]`

Can someone tell me on how can i fix this problem ? Thank you.

Json Output:-

```
{"foos":{"FooTypes [id=1, name=Test Foo]":[1,2,3]},"some":hello},{"foos":{"FooTypes [id=2, name=Another foo]":[5,6,7]}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit hard to help you since we don't have the Json structure you want to deserialize, but the problem here is Jackson has no idea how to deserialize your class **when it is used as a map key**. All the information Jackson as is a simple String, and your class provide no way of creating it with only a string.

There's 3 way to achieve this:

1. Add a single string argument constructor to your FooType class
2. Add a single string argument factory method (static) and annotate it with @JsonCreator
3. Use a custom `KeyDeserializer` and annotate the `foos` field with `@JsonDeserialize(keyUsing=YourDeserializer.class)`

IMHO the static factory method is the cleaner way.

Comment: I took your suggestion and use the static factory method which is much cleaner. It kinda sucks that i had to substring the (String)key so i can set the appropriate values of FooTypes to my object and then return it from the factory method.

Comment: When i try to return mapper.readValue(key,FooTypes.class) in my static factory method i get an exception for construct Key type. So i went the dirty way and substring the key, got the values and then set it in my object. Is there any other way to accomplish ?. This seems kinda hacky

Comment: You can't use the ObjectMapper in the static factory (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106552/json-weired-key-exception/12112508#12112508). And no, there's not really another way, this is kind of a limitation of JSON. Your JSON probably looks like {"name-id1":"somefoo","name-id2":someotherfoo"}; as long as you have a formal representation of FooType in a String form there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have non-primitive type as a map key (`FooTypes`) you'll need  to write your own custom deserializer as described in [Jackson wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers), because Jackson can't simply convert string value `"FooTypes [id=1, name=Test Foo]"` (which seems to be a result of `FooTypes.toString()`) into `FooTypes` instance.

On my opinion, serializing map with non-string keys is not really a good practice. JSON notation doesn't support anything but strings for map keys (as specified [here](http://json.org/)). A better approach, i think, would be to reorganize your data structure before serialization and after deserialization.